# Get relative position of an element to its parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can i get the position of an element relative to its parent?

Let's suppose we have an image object called 'clone', and a div as its parent:

```
var parent = clone.parent().offset();
var pos = clone.offset();
```

If i drag the image right in the top left corner of the div i will get as result almost the same values. But what about if i do this:

```
var top = pos.top - parent.top;
var left = pos.left - parent.left;
```

it'll give me the relative position of the image to its parent, right? But what happen if i have to store those values and display them on a different browser size?
The answer it's pretty easy, they won't show inside the div because the position may change.

After this little explaination, my question is:
Is there a way to avoid this kind of problem, and directly take the relative position to its parent?

This is the actual code i'm using, so you can give a look, and try to figure out how to make it works properly! http://dpaste.com/3M1MGQW

Comment: take a look at `.position()`: http://api.jquery.com/position/

Comment: if issue is size related can't you use percentage based positions? Hard to understand the higher level problem without a demo such as on jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

Have you set position: relative; to the parent so the positions are relative to it?

Well, any possitioning other tha static will work, but relative without specifing top and left may be the most painless

Comment: I already set the parent with a relative position, but i get a different value, and it's pretty ridicolous..

Comment: After going through your code the only thing I see that I would change is the $(this).append (clone); in line 48 with a direct access by id to the container $("#container_map").append (clone);

Comment: There's no need to change it, because it is referred to it :)

Comment: I know it should be the same but sometimes this does not refer to what we think it should...

Comment: I noticed that when i drop an element inside the div, it will magically appended elsewhere..